# Symfony2 - Doctrine - Filtering arrayCollection to get only one object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new in Doctrine. I have entities  and associations works fine. 
My issue:

I have three entities User, Comment, Comment_status.
Comment is connected to main table Finding but this doesnt matter in this case.

Association:  Comment <---1:n---> Comment_status <---n:1---> User
That should handle relation between users wathing list of comments and setting like/dislike for every of them.

I am using TWIG to show a list of comments on the page and thats enough for all data like "date", "like count" etc but if I want to get a comment_status for specified user (loged in wathing a page) I dont know how to get this.

if I return array to TWIG "comments" , then loop it for every one of them as "comment" i can access using {{ comment.content }} to data but with comment_status I have no idea bacause it is an array and I just want one element of this array which match to logged in user ID.

I suppose I have to make some DQL ask to DB but have no idea how to do this. 
I read some about Criteria in Doctrine but still no idea how to use it.

Can anybody give an step by step solution?

parts of my code:

Controller

```
> $comments = $em->getRepository('MySpecialBundle:Comment')
> ->findBy(array('finding' => $finding)); 
> 
> return array('comments' => $comments );
```

Comment entity (part which create association)

```
> /**  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment_status",
> mappedBy="comment", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
> */  protected $commentStatuses;
```

Comment_status entity (part which create association)

```
>  /**  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comment",
> inversedBy="commentStatuses")  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id",
> referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)  */  protected $comment;
/**

>  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\MainBundle\Entity\User",
> inversedBy="commentStatuses")  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id",
> referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)  */  protected $user;
```

User entity (part which create association)

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\SpecialBundle\Entity\Comment_status", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
     protected $commentStatuses;
```

I want to have a way to get (instead an array collection of all "commentStatuses") only one object which contains an user id of user logged in.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard I found a way to solve this.
The right answer is here:

```
$qb = $this->getEntitymanager()->createQueryBuilder();
$user = $qb->select('c, cs')
        ->from('MyBundle:Comment', 'c')
        ->leftjoin('c.commentStatuses', 'cs', 'WITH', 'cs.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $myLoggedInUser)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Leftjoin -  gives all records from Comment not only that contains commentStatus
WITH - choose only right commentStatuses

If I would use @Richard version with second join and WHERE it would show only Comments where user and commentStatus exists.

Anyway thans for help

Answer (score 0):

You can select and hydrate only the entities matching your criteria in a doctrine querybuilder query. This way you get an already filtered collection. E.g. Something like:

```
$qb = $this->getEntitymanager()->createQueryBuilder();
$user = $qb->select('u, cs, c')
        ->from('YourBundle:User', 'u')
        ->join('u.commentStatuses', 'cs')
        ->join('cs.comment', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('u', ':user')
        ->setParameter('user', $yourLoggedInUser)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This will get you your user and comments/statuses only applicable to that user.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, however I am still stuck.
I dont understand this: ->where($qb->expr()->eq('u', ':user')
where I can read about it ? 
You did that User is main entity, but I need Comment as a main entity.

Comment: I convert your query to make Comment to be main entity. Its works but not like I wanted. For ex.
If I have 3 comments, only 2 of them has comment_status form user 1 and user 2, then after that query I have got only 2 comments shown where commment_status exists. I want to show all  of them but insteas of array comments_status with user 1 and 2 only with specified one user

Comment: If I'm understanding you you want to show all comments regardless of comment status? You can change the joins to be leftJoin and that will give you all comments regardless of whether comment status exists or not.

Comment: Yes thats right @Richard but as I found out a solution thats was not enough. Left join is one thing but it still wont work when I join third table and use WHERE as you said. Instead of that I removed last join and WHERE and added WITH to first leftjoin. Now it work fine. Anyway thanks for your time. You helped me a lot, I wil post an answer working right to this case.